# If $S = \{x_1,...,x_{n-1}$} is linearly independent, how to prove $x\in S\iff $det$[x, x_1 ... x_{n-1}]=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

For the precondtion, $S$ and $x$ are in $ℝ^n$.

$\Rightarrow$ $S$ is linearly independent $\iff$ $Ax=0$ only has trivial solution $\iff$ $A$ is invertible (by inverse theorem) $\iff$ det$[x, x_1 ... x_{n-1}]\ne 0$

What happened here, how am I suppose to prove it? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: What does $A$ denote?

Answer (score 1):

All i think can be the problem is maybe $S = \{x_1,...,x_{n-1}\}$, as you have it stated if $x$ is already in $S$ then there is no reason to pose this question. 
In that case if $x \in S$ clearly we would then have $\{x,x_1,...,x_{n-1}\}$ is linearly dependent which would case the determinate to be zero. Similarly if the determinate is zero we must have that it is linearly dependent.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in S$ then the set is linearly dependent, hence the matrix is not invertible, hence the determinant is $0$.

If the determinant is $0$, then the matrix is not invertible, hence the column space is linearly dependent, and thus you can write $x$ as a sum.